# CSS Property to get the clicked url

Tags: css

Is there any CSS property to get the url when a link is clicked (without using the javascript/jquery)?

Comment: To *get* the url? What result are you hoping for when you click on a link?

Comment: you cant get the URL. but you can know, what the target is. `:target`

Comment: I need to add the css property within the html mail to track whether the user has clicked the url and which one is clicked

Comment: within the HTML mail? Please reformulate your question.

Comment: "whether the user has clicked the url and which one is clicked" That is a whole different story, please edit your question, so we may know, what you want to achieve…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [`:target`-pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target), which matches actually clicked anchor-targets, given in a URL after a `#`.

For example calling `index.php#paragraph1` would match

```
<p id="paragraph1">…</p>
```

in your CSS use something like:

```
:target { background: #fc0; }
```

To get some highlighting like here on SO, use something like:

```
[id] {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s ease;
    transition: background-color 2s ease; }
[id]:target {
    background-color: #ffa;
    color: #6a0504; }
```

To display the URL of an anchor in the moment it's clicked, use:

```
a[href]:active::after {
    content: ' (' attr(href) ')';
    /* more stylings */
}
```